# Openshift : Get Error while instralling rhc client tool in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: openshift, ubuntu-10.04, openshift-client-tools

I am using Ubunto 10.04.
I have already install Git,Ruby 1.8 and also rhc client tool.
The rhc gems is available in **[/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin]** directory.
but when I apply any command in console it generates error message.
[image: Console]

I had install git first then I install another component like Ruby and rhc client tool for this I am getting error.
I have seen issues about PATH variable but I am applying command from **[/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin]** directory
Then no need of setting PATH variable ( I think )
I have already update Ruby and rhc client
how I can resolve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin is not in your PATH you will need to run "./rhc" if you are in that directory.  If you add it to your PATH you will be able to run without the ./

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you have `rhc` installed correctly.  I'd try running `sudo gem install rhc`.

I love 10.04, but I think it comes with a pretty old version of RubyGems.  You may need to update to a newer version.

Here are some additional installation notes that are specific to Ubuntu:  https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/rhc-client-tools-install#ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem, what solved my problem was:

- type command "**sudo su**" (enter with your password)
- type command "**gem install rhc**"

Now, you will be able to use the command "**rhc setup**" or any other from openshift.